# How to add items to a set if a criteria is met without pulling a TypeError in this context

Tags: python

So to explain my code: I am trying to use a greedy-iterative-activity selector algorithm to solve this activity selection problem. I want to get the possible max activity count by adding a meeting in a list of meetings(a meeting is a list composed of two elements like `[0, 1]` where the 0 is the start time and the 1 is the end time) to a set if it meets a criteria and returning the length of that set. But I get a TypeError on `meetings_set.add(sorted_meetings[i])` which I think I know the reason for(lists are not immutable) but I do not know how to code around this. I closely followed the example of an optimal solution for activity selection problems to create this algorithm.

```
def answer(meetings):
     sorted_meetings = sorted(meetings, key = lambda x: int(x[1]))
     meetings_set = set((sorted_meetings[1]))
     k = 1

     meetings_len = len(meetings)

     for i in range(2, meetings_len):
             if sorted_meetings[i][0] >= sorted_meetings[k][1]:
                 meetings_set.add(sorted_meetings[i])
                 k = i

     return len(meetings_set)
```

Comment: Could you specifically provide the error message `TypeError` throws up?

Comment: Sorry prob should have in the first place `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each 'meeting' is a list of two integers. Sets must only contain hashable objects, and lists are not. A possible solution is to make the list into an immutable tuple before adding it to your 'meetings_set'.

```
meetings_set.add(tuple(sorted_meetings[i]))
```

Additionally, your code adds the start and end time of the first meeting as individual elements of the `meetings_set`.

The `set` constructor will make an initial set containing each element of the given iterable. `set((sorted_meetings[1]))` simply ignores the extra set of parenthesis and passes a list to the constructor, which is the reason for the bug. You can bypass this by saying:

```
meetings_set = set()
meetings_set.add(tuple(sorted_meetings[1]))
```

Aside:
I believe all your indices are off by one. Your current code does not consider the first element (I am not sure if this is intended). The following is your example code with the adjusted indices:

```
def answer(meetings):
     sorted_meetings = sorted(meetings, key = lambda x: int(x[1]))

     meetings_set = set()
     meetings_set.add(tuple(sorted_meetings[0]))
     k = 0

     meetings_len = len(meetings)

     for i in range(1, meetings_len):
          if sorted_meetings[i][0] >= sorted_meetings[k][1]:
               meetings_set.add(tuple(sorted_meetings[i]))
               k = i

     return len(meetings_set)
```

Comment: Sets do have an [add](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.add) method. His issue is something else. Please edit your response.

Comment: This solved a lot of the problems I was having. But I think it is still not iterating over the first item in the list for some reason because when given `meetings = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 5], [4, 5]]` it returns `print  meetings_set` as `[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 5]` which is nearly correct, but missing `[0, 1]`

Comment: The function as copy pasted from my example creates a finally dictionary of `{(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 5)}` for me. Did you change the index of the initially added meeting to `0` instead of `1`?

Comment: @jorgysen were you able to find the issue?

Comment: Yeah I did. I just added `meetings_set.add(tuple(sorted_meetings[0]))`  at the beginning of the for loop. Seems to be doing what I want. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh wait was that already in your revised version of my code? I missed it initially.

Comment: Something equivalent to that was, yes. Glad I could help!

Comment: @jorgysen if you have had you question solved, please accept an answer to close the question

Answer (score 1):

Lists are not hashable and hence cannot be used as set elements.  Tuples are hashable, so convert the lists to tuples before adding them to the set.  For example, to add a meeting to the set, use:

```
meetings_set.add(tuple(sorted_meetings[i]))
```

Comment: This solved the `TypeError` but produces a wacky set like this `set([2, 3, (3, 5)])` when I tested it with the list `meetings = [[0, 1], [1, 6], [2, 3], [3, 5], [4, 5]]`

Comment: I think you didn't change the second line where you initialize `meetings_set`.  When you call the set constructor `set(sorted_meetings[1])` it treats `sorted_meetings[1]` as an iterator, thus inserting two single integers into the set.

Comment: Think I got it figured out now. Thanks for the help, well explained.